# Pipe replacement with character

Tags: python

I have this code :

```
> list=str(raw_input('Enter pipe seprated list [PRIMARY|SECONDARY]:'))
> n_list="^"+list+"$" 
> print n_list
```

when I execute it, it prompts me as :

> Enter pipe separated list [PRIMARY|SECONDARY]:PRIMARY

as above if I give PRIMARY its gives me result as :

> ^PRIMARY$

and if provide the input as PRIMARY|SECONDARY:

> Enter pipe seprated list [PRIMARY|SECONDARY]:PRIMARY|SECONDARY

I am getting the output as :

> ^PRIMARY|SECONDARY$

here I want to get the output as :

**^PRIMARY$|^SECONDARY$** if I give the input **PRIMARY|SECONDARY**. Please help me to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do splitting according to `|`, add `^` and `$` at the start and end of each item. And then join them using `|`.

```
>>> s = 'PRIMARY|SECONDARY'
>>> print '|'.join(['^' + i + '$' for i in s.split('|')])
^PRIMARY$|^SECONDARY$
>>> s = 'PRIMARY'
>>> print '|'.join(['^' + i + '$' for i in s.split('|')])
^PRIMARY$
>>> s = 'PRIMARY|SECONDARY|TERTIARY'
>>> print '|'.join(['^' + i + '$' for i in s.split('|')])
^PRIMARY$|^SECONDARY$|^TERTIARY$
>>>
```

Comment: thanks a lot Avinash. Can you please let me know about 'i' here. what is the role of it.

Comment: @Rishab `i` is a temp variable which refers the current item. ie, iterating over the list and adds `^`, `$` to each item and forms a list.

Comment: Those `[ ]` are not necessary, you can pass a generator directly to `join`, without making it a list first.

Comment: @tobias_k but I hear that the generator obj alone should create extra loops when compared to list..

Comment: @AvinashRaj Hey, you are right! According to IPython's `%timeit`, using a list comprehension with `[ ]` is twice as fast as compared to a generator expression without `[ ]`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to split your string with `|` (pipe) and concate it with your prefix(^) and postfix($)

```
l=str(raw_input('Enter pipe seprated list [PRIMARY|SECONDARY]:'))
n_l = "|".join(["^" + l_t + "$" for l_t in l.split('|')])
print n_l
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness, as an alternative to the `split`/`join` solution already proposed, you could also just `replace` the `|` with `$|^`:

```
>>> s = 'PRIMARY|SECONDARY'
>>> '^' + s.replace('|', '$|^') + '$'
'^PRIMARY$|^SECONDARY$'
```

However, since in this solution you have to write both `^` and `$` twice, I would still prefer the `split`/`join` way.

Another solution: Instead of using the regex `'^PRIMARY$|^SECONDARY$'`, you could also use `'^(PRIMARY|SECONDARY)$'`. The behaviour should be the same.